# json_encode from MySQL - but change column names on output

Tags: php, json

I've never really used json_encode, but it's easy enough to do:

```
  $result = $dblink->query("SELECT * FROM Contracts LIMIT 3");

  $dbdata = array();

  while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
    $dbdata[]=$row;
  }

  echo json_encode($dbdata);

/tada!
```

However, if I want to give the output data custom "column names", is there a simple way of doing this?

So, rather than outputting something like:

```
[{"TableColumn1":"147","TableColumn2":"9","TableColumn3":"39","TableColumn4":"32","TableColumn5":"41"...
```

I can have something like:

```
[{"My Own Title":"147","My Own Title 2":"9","My own title 3":"39",...
```

Comment: Either _alias_ the individual columns in the SELECT statement, or modify the keys you insert into `$dbdata` first …

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$result = $dblink->query("SELECT * FROM Contracts LIMIT 3");

  $dbdata = array();

  while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {

    $rowarray = [];

    $rowarray['My Own Title 1'] = $row['TableColumn1'];
    $rowarray['My Own Title 2'] = $row['TableColumn2'];
    $rowarray['My Own Title 3'] = $row['TableColumn3'];

    $dbdata[]=$rowarray;

  }

  echo json_encode($dbdata);
```